# Styling not showing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm having an issue where the StyleSheets of my page is loading in all browsers except for Firefox.

Many of the errors that I get from Firefox read as:
**"Expected declaration but found '*'. Skipped to next declaration."**

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap so there are many **'*'** throughout the stylesheets and am wondering if this is a problem.

Please view this website in both Chrome vs. Firefox:
http://lol.99centbrains.com/HOMEFRIES/

Comment: No one wants to look at your web site. Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: you can click on the error and it'll take you straight to the offending line(s). And it's a hack for older IE (6?), so don't worry. Your site looks fine in firefox.

Comment: Thanks @slynagh ...just updated it so it should be looking fine rn.

Comment: No I am truthful. Go read the FAQ. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aight, so there was a typo when I was declaring my external stylesheets:

I had typed:

`<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="media">`

`<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">`

`<link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="media">`

Where it should have been:

`<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

`<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">`

`<link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Notice the **type="media"**

Comment: So is this OK now? It looks the same to me :D

Comment: @TarwinStroh-Spijer uh oh!  The page is still not appearing for you in Firefox?  Seems to be working on my end alright...

Comment: No, sorry just asking if it is fine for you now. That was not specific. I guess you answered for yourself ?